# oracle sql developer is truncating my results

Tags: sql, xml, oracle

I'm calling a stored function like this:

```
select XML_INVOICE.GENERATE_XML_DOC('84200006823') from dual;
```

The query results then show up in a table underneath, which I can right click and select "Export Data" -> XML

```
<?xml version='1.0'  encoding='UTF8' ?>
<RESULTS>
  <ROW>
    <COLUMN NAME="XML_INVOICE.GENERATE_XML_DOC('84200006823')" <![CDATA[<xml>yada yada</xml><morexml>...]]></COLUMN>
  </ROW>
</RESULTS>
```

The problem is the "..." - SQL Developer (2.1.0.63 on Linux) is not showing all the data - its truncating the result and appending the ellipsis.  This is of no use to me. How do I get it to export ALL of my data?

Comment: I'm deleting my answer since you've confirmed that the saved file does contain  "...". I can't reproduce with a similar call to a built-in function that produces a long output.  Just to be certain - if you do this in SQL*Plus (with the appropriate SET params) do you also get the same result? Also, from the function name and method it seems like the result is already in XML - why do you need to convert it again?

Comment: How large is the full XML. Can you post it here (so that we could insert into an environment and see if we can reproduce)

Comment: the XML is 70kb. I can't post the XML since its customer data. In any case, the actual content of the XML is not relevant - just the fact that its truncated.

Comment: Can you reproduce with a smaller, non-confidential example ?
PS. You do realize that the Export Data in XML format is there to export all the data (dates, numbers, strings, XML) in an XML format, not there specifically for exporting XML data ?

Comment: Yup, I do realize that. I tried export to CSV with the same result

Answer (score 11):

I was having the same issue in SQL Developer 4.  Here is what worked for me:

```
set long 100000;
set longchunksize 100000;
```

And then re-run the query.  You should now be able to see the full cell in the grid view and export it to csv as well.

(The OP is no longer with the same job or using Oracle, but this question is one of the first results in google, so hopefully this will help people having the same problem.)

Answer (score 0):

1) Insert the result of the SP into a table

select XML_INVOICE.GENERATE_XML_DOC('84200006823') into schema.table from dual;

(will be only one row)

Use exp to export table

EXP username/password@instance TABLES=(tablename)

Comment: I'd like to try this, but I'm not sure how. Don't I need to create the table first? what should the table schema be? and what is instance? It looks to me like this is on the server end, which I don't have access to. Isn't there some straightforward way to get the results of this query? I suppose I could write a whole program to do get the results of a query and write it out. *sigh* But isn't that what SQL developer is for?

Answer (score 0):

Another solution would be to write directly a XML file see example below, and adjust to fit:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE output_xml_file 
(inFileName         Varchar2 )   --user defined prefix for file name        
 AS

            fp UTL_FILE.FILE_TYPE;   
                v_filename  VARCHAR2(150);
            v_XML_Result VARCHAR2(4000);    

BEGIN

          v_filename:=infilename||'.xml';

          fp := UTL_FILE.FOPEN('c:\pathtofolder', v_filename, 'W', 4000);

          select XML_INVOICE.GENERATE_XML_DOC(inFileName) into v_XML_Result from dual; 

          UTL_FILE.PUT_LINE(fp, v_XML_Result);
          UTL_FILE.FCLOSE(fp);

          EXCEPTION

            WHEN OTHERS THEN

              UTL_FILE.FCLOSE(fp);
              raise;
    END output_xml_file;
    /
    SHOW ERRORS;
    GRANT EXECUTE ON output_xml_file TO PUBLIC;
```

Comment: I appreciate your response. However, this code creates a file on the server! The DBAs don't take kindly to that, and besides, they don't grant "mere" developers access to read files on the oracle server. So, this doesn't help me much.

Answer (score -1):

**Run as a Script** (F5) rather than as a Statement (Ctrl+Enter)

The output will then go to the Script Output window rather than the Query Output, and you will be able to Copy and Paste it

Comment: thanks for your response. I guess there's no pleasing me with this problem- I've moved to a new job since this happened, and we don't even use Oracle here, so I have no way to test this! But you get an upvote from me because it sounds reasonable.

Comment: This doesn't work.   I am having the same problem for `SELECT text
FROM all_views
WHERE view_name = 'xxx'` for a complex view I must reverse engineer.  The output with F5 is truncated even worse.